# Knp Pagination in symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I installed "Knp Paginator" and everything works fine but if i try to do a search in the search bar (this search bar does not depend on Knp Paginator) i have this error :

"Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Twig\Extension\PaginationExtension::render(): Argument #2 ($pagination) must be of type Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPaginationInterface, array given, called in... /var/cache/dev/twig/36/36da62d992e743004744882a10f47b6d89340c107d735e823c151b7c459ca09f.php on line 214"
[=>see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LJsd.png).

If i disable Knp Paginator, the search bar work again.

Thank you for your help.

this is my queryBuilder of search bar (ItemRepository):

```
public function findBySearch($search) 
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.city LIKE :val')
            ->setParameter('val', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('a.title LIKE :title')
            ->setParameter('title', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('a.city LIKE :city')
            ->setParameter('city', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('a.zipCode LIKE :zip')
            ->setParameter('zip', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('a.hiddenDetail LIKE :hiddenDetail')
            ->setParameter('hiddenDetail', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Controller (searchBar) :

```
   /**
    *@Route("/searchItem", name="searchItem")
    *
    */
   public function searchItem(Request $request, ItemRepository $itemRepository)
   {

       $search = $request->request->get('search');
       $items = $itemRepository->findBySearch($search);


       return $this->render('home/listItem.html.twig', [
           
           'items' => $items
           

       ]);
   }
```

Controller (Knp Paginator) :

```
public function listItem(ItemRepository $repository, PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request): Response
    {

       
        $data = $repository->findAll();

        // PAGINANTION KNP/PAGINATOR
        $items = $paginator->paginate(
            $data,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            8

        );

        return $this->render('home/listItem.html.twig', [

            'items' => $items,

        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

KNP is receiving an array from your `findAll()` function. You need to write a custom repo function to return the query builder itself, and KNP will complete the query for you with any extra necessities.

see https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-doctrine-relations/pagination

It was fruitful in my endeavors.

Edit: Also, I would take another look at your `andWhere()`'s. You can set one parameter for all of them at once, and just reuse the search term, if that would work for your situation.

```
public function findBySearch($search) 
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('
              a.city LIKE :val
              OR a.title LIKE :val
              OR a.city LIKE :val
              OR a.zipCode LIKE :val
              OR a.hiddenDetail LIKE :val')
            ->setParameter('val', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
            // if you want to use the paginator, leave these last two
            // lines off. Return just the qb.
    }
```